# How to to iterate through a specific time range in a logfile?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, logfile-analysis

For example:
`[2017-04-14 03:56:22,085109]`

If this is the time where event A happens, I want to go 15 minutes before this line in the logfile which will have thousands of line and I want to iterate through everyline in that period and look for specific keywords. Every line in the logfile has the time stamp with the same format.

Comment: Take a look at [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

Comment: I highly recommend you to use some database to run this type of analyzes instead of doing so in python.

Comment: You can use the [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) classmethod to convert the times in the file into Python `datetime` instances, which support comparisons. You can then use them to select the lines in the file that are within the interval of interest (assuming you have Event A's time also in a `datetime` instance).

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the desired lines with a start and end time.

`main.py`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

event_time = datetime.strptime('2017-04-14 03:56:22,085109', '%Y-%m-%d %X,%f')
event_start = event_time - timedelta(minutes=15)


def line_date(line):
    return datetime.strptime(line[1:27], '%Y-%m-%d %X,%f')


with open('example.log', 'r') as myfile:
    lines = filter(lambda x: event_start <= line_date(x) <= event_time,
                   myfile.readlines())


print(lines)
```

`example.log`

```
[2017-04-13 03:56:22,085109] My old log
[2017-04-14 03:55:22,085109] My log in less than 15 minutes ago
[2017-04-14 03:56:22,085109] My important event
[2017-04-14 03:57:22,085109] Log after my important event
```

But I recommend you to use **python3** (instead of python2). `filter` returns an iterator, instead of the full list.